How can I know it's left from reception and not left along the corridor?
I only know "left" is actually with "from reception" when I looked at the answer key that the answer is "I". It should be read as "left from reception" instead of "left along the corridor". "Along the corridor" directly follows "left" is so confusing. I thought it was talking left along the corridor. How can I know "along the corridor" is not modifying "left"?

The human resources department is at the front of this building, so
you head to the left along the corridor from reception, and it's the
second room you come to.



Can you clarify what it is that you’re asking?

I edited my question. Is it clear now?

Both to the left and along the corridor modify the verb head. Swapping the two prepositional phrases doesn’t change the sentence’s meaning. There aren’t varieties of left as though along the corridor might specify one from among them.

But my question is how I can know it's not left along the corridor. I read it as "left along the corridor" at first. I had to think very hard to get the real meaning.

The way you can tell is that the left along the corridor isn't a noun phrase, so it can't be the complement of the preposition to. The only way that it could be a noun phrase is if there were varieties of left, so that a question, "Which left?" could be answered with "The one along the corridor." And that is not the way left works in English; at least not in this context.

Said differently, if you ask yourself, "Head to what?" then the answer can be "to the left," but not so much "to the left along the corridor." This is because the phrase along the corridor describes how one should head, not toward what.

Thank you. Now, I understand. If there were a comma, It would be easier to understand: head to the left, along the corridor. But this is a listening test, which makes it even harder the find the answer as we are listening to it and not reading it.

Does this answer your question? Where is the corridor?

The key to understanding English is to imagine you're a rat.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about English.

"head to the left ... from reception" is your key phrase. That tells you that as you exit reception (by its one interior door) you turn to your left.
The phrase "along the corridor" only helps to tell you what you'll be seeing as you head in that direction.

(In other contexts, the "along" part might be the more important component. Supposing you had a big open field to your left and I said "go left along the river," I would be using the river to anchor your trajectory and expect you to stay close to it as you follow it. But in this case where all paths are enclosed and all turns are 90 degrees, it's just clarification.)
